# Why is the choice $\delta_n = 1/n$ so popular in this proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Yes, another limit question... ;)

---

I have searched for different proofs of the equivalency of epsilon–delta and sequential continuity. Most sources, *e.g.*, [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/sequential-criterion-for-the-continuity-of-a-function), [that](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/AC/cont.pdf), [here](https://www.math.byu.edu/~bakker/M341/Lectures/Lec19.pdf), and [there](https://books.google.ee/books?id=SaZYs-OKqJcC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=sequential+criterion+for+continuity&source=bl&ots=MCW0sCjnhx&sig=IFyWRGtgwjILLnz5Y-jS7BwH1Lc&hl=et&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjKp5WKj57OAhVIMZoKHc1RDQEQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=sequential%20criterion%20for%20continuity&f=false), all use the unexplained 'letting' of $$\delta_n=\frac{1}{n}.$$

The theorem is

> A function is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous.

Let us take [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/sequential-criterion-for-the-continuity-of-a-function) as the example. The final paragraph of the proof is what befuddles me.

> Now for each $n \in \Bbb{N^+}$ let $\delta_n=1/n.$ Choose $a_n$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_n=1/n$ and $|f(a_n)-f(c)|\geq\varepsilon_0$. But then we have a contradiction since $(a_n)$ converges to $c$ however $(f(a_n))$ does not converge to $f(c)$. Thus our assumption that $f$ was not continuous at $c$ was false.

'Let $\delta_n=1/n$'? The logic thereafter is understandable, and I am also aware that arriving at the best possible $\delta$ is not necessary, but come on. What is up with this $1/n$? What makes it so ubiquitous?

---

I do feel like I am supposed to be getting all of this $\varepsilon$–$\delta$ business by now, yet sometimes it cannot be any more frustrating.

Comment: Oh, and some of the links were purely  'for the sake of the example' :-). I do not actually expect a discussion involving general metric and topological spaces. Just why is $\delta_n = 1/n$ such a popular choice for $\delta$.

Comment: Any sequence $\delta_n \downarrow 0$ will work, $\delta_n = {1 \over n}$ is just convenient.

Comment: The point is that $1/n$ goes to $0$. Why would you choose anything else?

Comment: In fact, I think there is an error in the proof. It should be "Choose $a_n$ such that $|a_n - c| \le \delta_n$.

Comment: Haha. Saying *choose any sequence $(\delta_n)$ that converges to $0$* is much more sound and understandable. Instead writing a 'random' closed form implies, to me, a trick of sorts. Thanks everyone, and I do especially enjoy your answer, @Misakov!

Comment: @LinearChristmas That is very right. The point is you want some **sequence** and probably the easiest one would be $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pedantic reason could be due to the Archimedian Property, as I quote from *Elementary Analysis* by Kenneth A. Ross:

> **Archimedian Property.**
>
> If $a>0$ and $b>0$, then for some positive integer $n$, we have $na>b$
>
> This tells us that, even if $a$ is quite small and $b$ is quite large, some integer multiple of $a$ will exceed $b$. Note that if we set $b=1$, we obtain the following assertion:
>
> If $a>0$, then $\frac{1}{n}<a$ for some positive integer $n$.

Going back to the proof you gave and notice this part:

> Choose $a_n$ such that $|a_n - c|<\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$

The nice thing about using $\delta_n =\frac{1}{n}$ is that you can actually apply Squeeze Theorem because we have both left hand side and right hand side being sequences. As a result of that, it becomes obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n -c|=0$, which really means that $a_n\to c$ as $n\to \infty$.

If, instead, you write

> Choose $a_n$ such that $|a_n - c|<\delta$

Then it becomes a little bit tricky, perhaps especially for beginners to realize what really is going on.

Answer (score 1):

It is partly because of the answer above (or below), and partly because one can choose $(\delta_n)$ to be any sequence that converges to $0$ for the proof to be valid. Since $(\frac{1}{n})$ is the 'simplest one' of these for most people, and since proving there exists a sequence that converges to $0$ without just explicitly giving one is considered more annoying, people often choose $(\frac{1}{n})$.